# How to get Action Mode working with a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-inflate, action-menu

I'm trying to get a contextual menu using the Action Mode where I can select an item in a ListView by long-clicking on it. I created a MultiChoiceListener according to [this reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) and made a ItemLongClickListener wich sets an item as checked which is needed for the Action Mode to work according to [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283181/how-do-i-use-a-selectable-list-with-a-contextual-actionbar).

My problem is, that, even if the item long clicked animation is playing, the ActionMenu doesn't inflate.

ListView Code:

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setLongClickable(true);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long id) {

            Cursor cursor = db.getSubject(id);
            String subject = null;
            try {
                subject = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subject"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Marks.class);
            intent.putExtra("selected", subject);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                listView.setItemChecked(arg2, true);
                return true;
            }

        });

        listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                    long id, boolean checked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not see any code in there to actually start the action mode. That is something your `OnItemLongClickListener` needs to do, such as:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> view, View row,
                                 int position, long id) {
    modeView.clearChoices();
    modeView.setItemChecked(position, true);

    if (activeMode == null) {
      activeMode=host.startActionMode(this);
    }

    return(true);
  }
```

A full sample project demonstrating manually using an action mode like this can be found at: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionMode/Manual

Note that this project demonstrates using action modes via ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: There's no seperate class handling the ActionMode in Googles example. Do I need to create a seperate class to use it?

Comment: @BlueHazard: That's up to you. You need something that implements `ActionMode.Callback` for use with `startActionMode()`. I elected to delegate that to a separate class. If you want to have your activity implement `ActionMode.Callback`, that should be perfectly fine.

Comment: why not implement `MultiChoiceModeListener` and use `onCreateActionMode` ?

Comment: @nurettin: The OP does. That is insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

CommonsWare's answer is great. If what you want is a MultiChoiceModeListener that selects one element by long-clicking it, this code might help you:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MultiChoiceModeListener{
    private ListView mListView;
    // ...

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        mListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {                
                mListView.setItemChecked(arg2, true);
            }
        });
    }
```

In my case i do it with single click, but you can change OnItemClickListener for OnItemLongClickListener or any other that you prefer.